# How to check for OpenSSL Oracle Vulnerability for internal application?

Tags: apache, security, openssl

I am trying to test our internal applications(DEV and QA enironments) which are behind the firewall for OpenSSL Oracle Vulnerability. I am able to run Qualys(ssllabs.com) to check for Oracle Vulnerability of our production application. Am wondering are there any such free tools/methods to check for Oracle Vulnerability of internal applications?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww thanks for letting me know..I'll move my question to  Super User or Webmaster Stack Exchange